# What if incumbent president is defeated in re-election, and resigns before Jan 20?

Tags: united-states, president

What if the incumbent president is defeated in his re-election in November, and resigns before the Jan 20 inaugural of his opponent?   Does the president-elect get sworn in early/immediately, or does the 'old' Vice-president become president for a few days, until the Jan 20 ceremony?
  Why I ask: Jennifer Rubin has suggested a scenario where Trump would resign at 11:45 AM on Jan 20; Pense then becomes president for 15 minutes, and issues a blanket pardon to Trump. (Maybe while they are all on stage with the Democratic party's president-elect.)

Comment: One might wonder why on Earth Pence would do that, though.  Doesn't seem to be anything in it for him, other than the permanent clouding of his reputation.  Consider that Ford's pardon of Nixon was a major factor in him losing the election to Carter.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the president-elect get sworn in early/immediately, or does the
>   'old' Vice-president become president for a few days, until the Jan 20
>   ceremony? Why I ask: Jennifer Rubin has suggested a scenario where
>   Trump would resign at 11:45 AM on Jan 20; Pense then becomes president
>   for 15 minutes, and issues a blanket pardon to Trump.

Rubin's scenario is correct. The "old" Vice-President becomes President for a few days until January 20.

Comment: Can you provide sources (I am not the downvoter, just curios)?